# Search list in string characters

Tags: python, string, list, search

I have to search if a word doesn't have a vowel, and then put them in another list.
I can't make it work, and I don't understand why.

```
    for i in range(len(Cadena)):
    if all Vocales[] not in Cadena:
        Lista.append(Cadena[i])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
word = 'apple'
vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','A','E','I','O','U']
for letter in word:
    if letter in vowels:
        #this word has a vowel, do something
    else:
        # this word doesn't have a vowel.
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your variables mean, but your problem is simple.

Here is the solution:

```
# array with words that you to sort into two groups
words = ["abc", "def", " ggg"]
vowels = ["a", "e", " i", "o", " u"] # possibly include "y"
numVowels = len(vowels)

withVowels = []   # words with vowels
withoutVowels = [] # words without vowels

# categorize words
for w in words:
    for i, v in enumerate(vowels):
        if v in w:
            withVowels.append(w)
        elif i == (numVowels -1):
            withoutVowels.append(w)
```

At the end of this for loop, the withVowels will contain `["abc", "def"]` and withoutVowels will contain `[" ggg"]`

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def vocales(text):
    #with regular expression.
    print re.findall("[aeiouÁÉÍÓÚ]", text.lower(), re.IGNORECASE)
    #or verifying letter by letter
    print [e for e in text if e in "aeiouÁÉÍÓÚ"]
    #Shows the characters that are not vowels
    print [e for e in text if e not in "aeiouÁÉÍÓÚ"]
    #Returns false if it has vowels
    return not len([e for e in text if e in "aeiouÁÉÍÓÚ"])

vocales("Hola mundo. Hello world")
```

Output:

```
['o', 'a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'o']
['o', 'a', 'u', 'o', 'e', 'o', 'o']
['H', 'l', ' ', 'm', 'n', 'd', '.', ' ', 'H', 'l', 'l', ' ', 'w', 'r', 'l', 'd']
False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a string with all your vowels, then you can use list comprehension to check your words against this string

```
vow = 'aeiou' 
words = ['apple', 'banana', 'vsh', 'stmpd']

w_vowels = [i for i in words if any(k in vow for k in i)]
wo_vowels = [i for i in words if not any(k in vow for k in i)]

print(w_vowels) # => ['apple', 'banana']
print(wo_vowels) # => ['vsh', 'stmpd']
```

Expanded Loops without `any`:

```
w_vowels = []
for i in words:
    for k in i:
        if k in vow:
            w_vowels.append(i)
            break
wo_vowels = []
for i in words:
    for k in i:
        if k in vow:
            break
    else:
        wo_vowels.append(i)
```